# Overwrite Default ChartJS Variables with Webpack

Tags: webpack, vue.js, chart.js, babeljs

I'm working on a project with Webpack and ChartJS. I would like to overwrite a default setting in ChartJS but I am unsure how to do this since I am new to Webpack.

Normally, I would just add this code after importing ChartJS:

```
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.callbacks.label = function(tooltipItem, data){
  return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')
}
```

However, since I'm using Vue components, I'm importing ChartJS a lot, and there's no point in overwriting the defaults by copy-pasting this code into every one of my files that uses ChartJS.

Is it possible to overwrite this default somewhere in my Webpack configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to change the global settings of ChartJS without doing it in every component.
If you import and change it in one file (for example your main component/page) you can just change the settings as you demonstrated and it will apply to every other component which will import it. Webpack handles this for you.

https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/234

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll definitely check it out. However, I'm not using Vue ChartJS, I'm using VueJS and normal ChartJS. Would this (pun intended) change anything?

Comment: It should also work with normal VueJS, because this is something that Webpack handles for you.

Comment: Great, I will test it later today and then hopefully mark as answered!